# How to use managed code from unmanaged code?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, unmanaged

How do I call a .NET code from native C++ (unmanaged code)? I want to expose .NET code to my unmanaged (C++) application and then use them. More specifically, I want to call C# from native C++ :). I know there are many ways but can you tell me the pros and cons of each? By the way, I don't want to use COM so what are the options now?

Is it possible that I wrap the C# code in C++/CLI and then call it from C++? If so, how do I do that? How do I wrap the C# in C++/CLI and then call it from C++?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exporting dll functions to unmanaged programs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647766/exporting-dll-functions-to-unmanaged-programs)

Answer (score 5):

I've written about it just recently. It was about Delphi, but that doesn't mean it won't work with C++ as well.

[.NET component in DELPHI 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624321/net-component-in-delphi-2009/1634613#1634613)

Even without knowing much about C++, I still know that IUnknown and COM-compatible interface references should be usable just fine from C++ (in the case you need to pass objects, not just structures).

- You can use Microsoft's C++/CLI to reference your C# code and export it as ordinary DLL functions.
- You can also download an [MSBuild task](http://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports) I wrote, that allows you to export function directly from C#.  Analogous to how DllImportAttribute is used.

This C# code would export a function "YourExportName" that can be used just like any c-compatible function would be used.

---

```
class Sample
{
   [DllExport("YourExportName")]
   static int TestFunction(int left, int right)
   {
     return left + right;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always embed Mono. I have personally done it in two projects so far and it's easy enough. Follow [Embedding Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You could [expose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6(VS.71).aspx) the managed component as COM object.

Answer (score 0):

Check [How to call a managed DLL from native Visual C++ code in Visual Studio.NET or in Visual Studio 2005](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736)