# Pure Win32 API application (no frameworks), needs access to a .NET component

Tags: winapi, com, com-interop

What's the optimal technique? Wrap the .NET component (Class written in .NET 3.5) in COM and instantiate in Win32? The component has events so this must support component driven callbacks into the Win32 API application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution that meets your specifications is COM.

Comment: That's not true.  A C++/CLI wrapper would also work. The Win32 application would have to pass a function pointer to the wrapper for the wrapper to call, but it would work fine.  It would be too much work, but the wrapper dll could also use use other methods such as RPC

Comment: @dscaeffer A C++/CLI wrapper would work but the OP wanted pure Win32.

Comment: I believe he was saying he wanted pure Win32 for the application, not the wrapper, but if not, then you are correct.  If he does not have access to the original component source then his COM wrapper will also not be pure Win32

Comment: @dschaeffer You may very well be right, but it seems rather like OP has lost interest in the question.  It's just you and me!!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your preference and how the .NET component is set up.

Wrapping it in COM works fine, and gives you a object based interface which is usually nice.  You also get a type library which is nice if the interface is complicated.

For APIs with a simple interface, I usually prefer making the wrapper in C++/CLI.  The wrapper then has direct access to the .NET component, and you  can easily export the wrapper functions with __declspec(dllexport).  It is often quicker to set up this type of wrapper than having to set up COM.

Here are a couple of links you might find useful:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/bridge.aspx

[How to use managed code from unmanaged code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635679/how-to-use-managed-code-from-unmanaged-code)